# Избавиться от лишнего if

Tags: c++, ооп, архитектура, проектирование

Есть классы `Deck`(колода) и `Card`(карточка). Задача при добавлении карты в колоду обновить описание колоды. Проблема в том, что при обновлении базы данных, возникают две проверки if на тип карточки (является ли карточка новой или карточкой для повторения)

```
struct Card
{
    bool is_new();
    bool is_review();
};


struct Deck
{
    int new_cards()    { return m_newCards; }
    int review_cards() { return m_reviewCards; }

    void add_card(Card card)
    {
        m_cards.push_back(card);

        if (card.is_new) { m_newCards++ }
        else if (card.is_review()) { m_reviewCards++ }

        m_totalCards++;
    }
private:
    std::vector<Card> m_cards;
    int m_newCards;
    int m_reviewCards;
    int m_totalCards;
};

struct Mapper
{
    void update_deck(Deck& deck, Card card)
    {
        int newCards {deck.new_cards()};
        int reviewCards {deck.review_cards()};
        int totalCards {deck.total_cards() + 1};

        if (card.is_new()) { newCards++; }
        else if (card.is_review()) { reviewCards++; }

        update(deck, newCards, totalCards, reviewCards);

        deck.add_card(card);
    }
}
```

Шаблон State вроде не подходит, карточка внутри себя поведение не меняет.

Создать классы `NewCard` и `ReviewCard` и перегрузить метода `add_card(NewCard)`, `add_card(RepeatCard)`, но тогда придется держать карточки в разных контейнерах

Можно еще убрать проверку внутри метода `add_card(card)` и реализовать методы `set_new_cards(int)`, `set_repeat_cards(int)` у класса `Deck`

Как лучше поступить?

Comment: *"при обновлении базы данных, возникают две проверки if на тип карточки"* Что в этом плохого?

Comment: Не знаю, а что хорошего?) Одно и тоже действие два раза подряд.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что is_new и is_review всегда буду противоположны?

Comment: Ну вообще да, противоположны, но может быть ситуация когда оба метода вернут false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал следующим образом: класс `Card` объявляет в себе `enum State`, который означает состояние карты (новая, просмотренная, перевернутая и т.п. в рамках полета фантазии). Методы, делающие что-то с картой, изменяют её внутренне состояние.

Далее на основе этих состояний уже можно реализовать, если так корректно будет выразиться, **вычисляемые** свойства для колоды, например, количество показанных карт, количество новых карт (и т.п., опять же в рамках нашей фантазии).

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

/**
 *  Класс карты.
 */
class Card
{
public:
    /// имеет два состояния: НОВАЯ и ПРОСМОТРЕННАЯ карта
    enum State {CARD_NEW, CARD_REVIEW};

    /// при создании карты устанавливаем ее состояние, как НОВАЯ
    Card() :
        state_(State::CARD_NEW)
    {
    }

    /// при вытаскивании с колоды меняем состояние карты на ПРОСМОТРЕННУЮ
    void showCard()
    {
       state_ = State::CARD_REVIEW;
    }

    State state() const { return state_; }

private:
    State state_;
};

/**
 * Класс колоды.
 */
class Deck
{
public:
    void addCard(const Card& card)
    {
        deck_.push_back(card);
    }

    int total() const
    {
        return deck_.size();
    }

    /**
     * Вышеописанные "вычисляемые" свойства
     */ 

    int newCardsCount() const
    {
        return getCardsCount(Card::State::CARD_NEW);
    }

    int reviewCardsCount() const
    {
        return getCardsCount(Card::State::CARD_REVIEW);
    }

    /**
     * В это место будет отсылочка по тексту ниже.
     */

private:
    int getCardsCount(Card::State state) const
    {
        /// используя лямба-выражение, записываем всё минималистично и красиво
        return count_if(deck_.begin(), deck_.end(), 
                        [state](const Card &card) { return card.state() == state; });
    }

    vector<Card> deck_;
};

int main()
{
    const int count = 100000;
    Card cards[count ];
    Deck deck;

    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    /// делаем каждую третью карту из десяти созданных показанной   
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 3)
    {
        cards[i].showCard();
    }

    /// добавляем все карты в колоду
    for (auto card: cards)
    {
        deck.addCard(card);
    }

    int newCards = deck.newCardsCount();
    int reviewCards = deck.reviewCardsCount();

    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int microseconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();

    cout << "New cards count: " << newCards << endl
         << "Review cards count: " << reviewCards << endl
         << "execution time: " << microseconds << " microseconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на экран:

```
New cards count: 66666
Review cards count: 33334
execution time: 1016
```

В чем же преимущества данного подхода? Они следующие:

1. **Нет проблем со счетчиками**. Каждый раз в меняя состояние одной карты в колоде, придется изменить значения как минимум двух счетчиков (выстрелы себе в ногу никто не отменял, а все потому что забыл уменьшить или увеличить какой-то счетчик... а если этот счетчик еще используется где-то для прохода по массиву, то привет *Undefined Behavior*). А если состояний много...
2. **Простота добавления нового свойства**. При появлении необходимости обрабатывать какое-то новое свойство, то добавляем еще одно значение в `enum State {CARD_NEW, CARD_REVIEW, CARD_SOME_NEW_STATE};` и следующий метод в место, к которому была обещанная отсылка в коде выше (**всего 3 строчки**, в случае с `if` или `switch` думаю вышло бы больше):

```
int getSomeNewStateCount() const
{
    return getCardsCount(Card::State::CARD_SOME_NEW_STATE);
}
```

3. **Имхо, более приятный код**, который проще читать и понимать, нежели то, что может получиться при, например, состояниях от 3-х и выше, построенных вокруг `if` и `switch`, со всеми счетчиками, и вытекающей из этого громоздкостью.

**Из отрицательных моментов** можно сказать, что есть необходимость полного прохода по вектору `deck_` всякий раз, когда потребуется узнать количество карт определенного состояния. Однако считаю, что это допустимая "жертва" в пользу качества кода, скорости разработки и личного удобства.

Comment: К сожалению, я наверное ввел в заблуждение когда назвал классы Card и Deck. Подразумевается не игральная колода, а колода flash card(существующий аналог программы Anki и подобных) для запоминания, поэтому в колоде может быть хоть сколько карточек. Проблема вот еще в чем, пока пользователь не обратился к конкретной колоде(не кликнул по кнопке колоды) из таблицы Cards в базе дынных ничего не будет загружено, то есть deck.total() будет возвращать 0. А мне нужны данные по кол-ву карточек в меню, поэтому я в таблице Decks храню их.

Comment: @stade, тем не менее, принцип я бы оставил тот же

Comment: @stade, я обновил ответ с проверкой на 100000 элементов. Время выполнения достаточно приемлемое (может отличаться на разных устройствах).

Comment: А как мне поступить с отложенной загрузкой колод? Например при старте программы в меню две колоды: Physics(Total Cards 300), English(Total Cards 1000). Пока пользователь не нажал на колоду будет выгружена только таблица Decks(хранит название колоды и кол-во карт). Когда нажмет на English из базы выгрузятся карточки из этой колоды. А с вашим решением мне загружать сразу всю базу данных при старте?

Comment: А в чем проблема, если кол-во карточек в колоде приходит вместе с ее названием? Никто же не запрещал модифицировать код выше. Инициализируйте `Deck` количеством элементов, а функцию `int total() const` можно реализовать как-то так: `return deck_.size() ? deck_.size() : countFromConstructor;`. Если мы добавляли карточки в колоду, возвращаем реальное значение, если нет, то значение из БД. Опять же в рамках полета фантазии.